# http_proxy lists port of 3128 but when I netstat that port is not open. What does this indicate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, environment-variables

My proxy values suggest that `localhost:3128` is being used as a proxy.  I should add that I personally added these environmental variables in an `.sh` file in my `profile.d` folder.  A tutorial indicated I needed to do this to enable a particular Google service.

```
$ env

HTTP_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
HTTPS_PROXY=http://localhost:3128
http_proxy=http://localhost:3128
https_proxy=http://localhost:3128
```

However when I `netstat` the output doesn't indicate that the port is in use.  So I assume that setting the environment variables didn't necessarily turn on a proxy although I'm not certain of that.

```
$ netstat -tuplen

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      988        25226      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20028      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          26841      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          26819      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          26843      -
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          20030      -
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          32013      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          26842      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          26827      -
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          26844      -
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          21892      -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           0          20029      -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           0          22534      -
udp6       0      0 fe80::c37:2dff:fe7d:546 :::*                                0          28138      -
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                0          20031      -
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                0          22535      -
```

A second piece of data indicates that something is not right.  I'm having trouble with AWS SES.

When I test my connection I get an error.

```
$ aws ses verify-email-identity --email-address test@example.com

Failed to connect to proxy URL: "http://localhost:3128"
```

However when I comment out my .sh file and reboot the server the `http_proxy` environmental variables are gone and AWS SES works as expected.

So does the output mismatch between `env` and `netstat` indicate anything?  I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: All one can say is that the proxy server configured by the environment variables is obviously not running, or perhaps it is running but not listening (unlikely). Your SES connection doesn't work because the `aws` command is configured by those variables. Where the value of `localhost:3128` comes from, and what kind of proxy server is supposed to be running (`squid`, probably?), I can't tell. **Solution**: Either don't use these proxy settings, or run a proxy server that listens at port 3128.

Comment: Did you actually install the proxy?

Comment: @berndbausch I never installed squid.  I added those env variables to get reCAPTCHA Enterprise operational.  And for some reason simply adding those allowed it to communicate externally.  I do have NGINX installed on my front facing IP and it forwards requests to a Node.js upstream server.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I only installed the env variables.  I never installed squid.  I do have NGINX installed as per my comment above.  As you can probably tell I'm a Linux newbie.

Comment: These variables have the effect that certain programs use a proxy server listening at localhost port 3128. If nothing listens, such programs fail. It seems that the AWS CLI is one of those. Could it be that some component of reCAPTCHA Enterprise has the proxy function but is currently not active?